# How to override Woocommerce Single Product template page with Avada child-theme

Tags: woocommerce

I need to redesign the default woocommerce template of a product page.
I have tried this with copying the structure of avada to child-theme.

`/theme/avada/woocommerce/single-product/*` to `/theme/avada-child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/`

But I can not find a template that displays the whole page. Only `title.php` does change the title. But can not find the rest of the page.
I need to delete these parts:

```
 - short description
 - sku
 - social media buttons
```

How can I redesign a complete product page is new for me.
May be someone can give me a start where to find the templates.

Thanks in advance.
Herman

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content in the single-product.php template
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_single_product hook.
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     */
     do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

     if ( post_password_required() ) {
        echo get_the_password_form();
        return;
     }
?>

<div itemscope itemtype="<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_schema(); ?>" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             */
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .summary -->

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the Avada theme, but in default WooCommerce you can see in the [`content-single-product.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-single-product.php) template that short description and social buttons are added via **hook**. So to remove them you'd need to use `remove_action()` from your theme's `functions.php`.

If this doesn't work as is, please review [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) because you just need to make sure that the parameters match up to what the Avada theme is doing.

```
function so_35252579_remove_hooks(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'so_35252579_remove_hooks' );
```

To remove the SKU, you could either disable skus, or if you need them but don't want to display them on the front end then you would need to override [`single-product/meta.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/templates/single-product/meta.php)

Comment: Helgo, that is a part of the solution. Thanks. How to rearrange the divers hooks is stil open. I do not see any kind of css in the php file.

Comment: There wouldn't be any CSS the PHP file. Rearranging the hooks is done by removing the functions from one hook (like above) and using [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to add them to another. If you will edit your question to paste in the Avada theme's `content-single-product.php` template, I can confirm if my code will work to remove the excerpt and sharing.

Comment: Helga. I have a problem to understand what you mean with: "If you will edit your question to paste in the Avada theme's content-single-product.php template," Hope you can explain.

Comment: Find the file `content-single-product.php` in the Avada theme and copy the contents and paste it into your question. But you have accepted this as the answer, so I presume it solved the question. If so, there's not need to paste any further code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. You can write it as a plugin or simply copy paste to functions.php. Note the following

- locate_template function is first look at active theme root directory for the file. If the file is present there then it will use. otherwise plugin folder will be check.
- First if condition simply checking whether the current page is showing is single product page. you can add more conditional tags based on you requirement.

**add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', 'so_29984159_custom_content_template_part', 10, 3 );**

```
function so_29984159_custom_content_template_part( $template, $slug, $name ){
        if ( $slug == 'content' && $name == 'single-product')  {

            if( locate_template('content-single-product-custom.php') ) {
                $template = locate_template( $file_name );
            } else {
                // Template not found in theme's folder, use plugin's template as a fallback
                $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-single-product-custom.php';
            }

        }
        return $template;
    }
```